# Is it good to use a static method and static class to read and write to a json file?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I am trying to write and read from a JSON file. Is the use static method  good ?, and how do I improve the performance of this code

```
public static class Service
{
    private static JsonContainer ReadAll()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.JsonFilePath)))
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonContainer>(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }         
    }

    private static bool WriteAll(JsonContainer data)
    {
        // serialize JSON directly to a file
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Constants.JsonFilePath)))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(file, data);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an old school way of doing it. Modern code would implement the methods as part of an interface so that this service (or a stub of it) could be injected. Also, `HttpContextBase` would be injected instead of accessed through `HttpContext.Current`/

Comment: Asking "is it good to use a static method for X" without further context is like asking "is it good to write code on a Tuesday?".

Answer (score 0):

[A very nice article why to avoid static classes](https://blog.aspiresys.pl/technology/why-static-classes-are-evil/)

Some extra points:

1. You can't extend them
2. You'll end up with all serialization code on there and your code will become umanagable.
3. You already made it too general and dropped all type safety
4. They tend to violate sinlge responsibiliy principle
5. They hinder unit testing
6. They can't be injected by DI containers

I can't really think of any other class than `Math` that makes sense (I'm sure there are some), and that's because the concepts are core, don't change and are not extended.

Any other non trivial representation would not benefit from it.

Comment: "You can't extend them" - but you can't extend *any* types outside your project in .NET anyway - you can only derive from non-sealed classes, but inheritance should not be used as a substitute for mixins, so point 1 isn't really valid.

Comment: Why do you think that? I'd really like to hear your opinion. Sealed classes are declared that way for a reason. An abstract class could be considered a mixin, depending on the definition. All just tools to be used accordingly. Using static classes is effectively sealing without good reason.

Comment: Despite C# being a modern-ish language, it still isn't designed around the notion of the _pit of success_: you've pointed out some of the many practical and theoretical disadvantages of `static` methods, but `static` methods offer many syntactical and (developer's) workflow conveniences where the "correct" way of doing things (e.g. using the singleton pattern instead of static methods; convenience of arbitrary call-sites, not needing to add another parameter to a method - or member to a context class - in order to pass a reference to the owning interface instance, etc)...

Comment: ...so it's hard to argue for "DI everywhere!" when there are many compelling alternatives that have their own advantages and without the sheer amount of legwork required to get DI working in any application and/or dependencies (e.g. having to add a dependency on a DI library, having to set-up `ConfigureServices`, having to change `ClassName.StaticMethod()` references to either `this.injectedService.StaticMethod()` or `ClassName.DefaultInstance.StaticMethod()` (which makes code unnecessarily verbose), loss of access via `using static`, always requiring an extra (superfluous) `this` parameter...